# Overall and partial MOSFET voltage gain

Tags: mosfet, resistance, gain, formula-derivation

I am researching studies for common source MOSFET amplifier and I found two different terms for voltage gain - overall and partial.

- What is the difference between overall and partial gain when talking about MOSFETs?
- What do each one of them mean?
- Are both used in practice when applying equations to real circuits?

Where partial voltage gain is defined as

[image]

And overall voltage as

[image]

Circuit schematic

[image]

Equivalent small signal circuit
[image]

Comment: Explain to me why you ask questions about a circuit, have components like Rg1, Rsig which are unclear what they are. Yet you do not bother to show the circuit you're talking about. No circuit so I'm moving on.

Comment: The second one includes the voltage divider due to the voltage source impedance and the biasing voltage divider

Comment: @FakeMoustache: How about now? Can you recognize the circuit?

Comment: @Mike: Yes but does the overall voltage gain formula makes value more accurate? Since it includes also the voltage divider.

Comment: Of course. But if Rs is very small in comparison to the parallel combination of the two bias resistors you'll get the first equation.

Comment: @Mike: Yeah but overall gain formula will still apply in that case, right?

Comment: Av is the transfer from gate G to drain D. Gv is the transfer from the input voltage source to the output. That's it, no more no less. There is no case that one or the other formula is not valid. In practice we seldom have to use the more complex Gv formula as the attenuation from Rsig, Rg1 and Rg2 is usually negligible. It would be "silly" to first attenuate the signal and then amplify it again now would it ?

Comment: @FakeMoustache: So Gv formula is not so commonly used in practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember my MOSFETs class would often have a DC voltage source that was connected to the gate and drain of the MOSFET. The gate resistors would form a divider (R_G1 and R_G2) and bias the circuit, just like the equations you have listed. I believe you are getting information from a few sources that have different circuits (maybe a class and online?). I will answer your questions assuming what you're doing is similar to my college classes...

1) What is the difference between overall and partial gain when talking about MOSFETs?

2) What do each one of them mean?

3) Are both used in practice when applying equations to real circuits?

1 & 2) 
Partial gain is Vo/Vi (where Vi is the input at the gate). 
Overall gain is Vo/Vsig (where Vsig is your signal BEFORE the blocking capacitor.

3) Depends on the circuit. Most people will not use MOSFETs for amplifiers and will instead buy an op amp or other IC, at least in automotive circuits. If you go to work somewhere that designs analog circuits, it will probably be more common, but I can't say for sure.

Comment: Different sources yes, online also yes but class, no (at least not for unipolar transistors). I probably wouldn't be searching for answers online if I would had real person to ask about it (prof. for example). But since I don't, I just have to do it the hard way and also longer one.

Comment: Are you sure about 1) and 2) one? Because till now this seems to be most logic explanation.

Comment: Try to derive the equations you've posted. They should come out the same for A and G. It's also a good conceptual exercise.

Comment: Great, I will. One more thing - what makes small-signal circuit small - where is the boarded between large-signal and small-signal circuits? Ok, I get it large--high powers, small--low powers. But are there any other terms that define circuit small-signal or large-signal?